# Assigning values in Verilog: difference between assign, <= and =

Tags: verilog, assign

I have just started learning Verilog and I've seen these three lines from different sources. I am confused about the difference between the three:

1. c <= a&b;
2. assign c = ~a;
3. c = 1'b0;

These lines seem to assign a value to c but what's the difference? Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1) `<=`non-blocking and is performed on every positive edge of clock. these are evaluated in parallel so no guarantee of order. An example of this would be a register.

2) `assign =`continual assignment to wire outside an always statement. value of LHS is updated when RHS changes.

3) `=`blocking assignment, inside always statements enforces sequential order.

Comment: I think it is also worth noting non-blocking (`<=`) and blocking (`=`) must be used inside an `initial` or `always` block.